# Change one button background color onClick and revert previously clicked button to default background (8 Buttons)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, nodemon

I have a column of 8 buttons and would like only one button to be toggled(yellow) at a time and the rest of the buttons remain default(green).
I am having a bear of a time getting the function to execute on click. Meaning no colors are changing.

I have been using this post [How to select and change color of a button and revert to original when other button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508065/how-to-select-and-change-color-of-a-button-and-revert-to-original-when-other-but)
as my reference and has helped me understand querySelectors and changing classes but for the life of me I cant see why my application isnt working.
`Console.log('test)` fires right after the for loop is called but if put below the `onClick` it does not fire.

JS

```
for (button in buttons) {
    buttons[button].onclick = function() {
        console.log('test')
        var yellowButton = document.querySelectorAll(".yellow")[0];
        if (this.className == "green") {
            if (yellowButton) yellowButton.className = "green";
            this.className = "yellow";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
            <button class="green">UPKEEP</button>
            <button class="green">DRAW</button>
            <button class="green">MAIN</button>
            <button class="green">COMBAT</button>
            <button class="green">MAIN</button>
            <button class="green">END TURN</button>
            <button class="green">CLEANUP</button>
```

CSS

```
button{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.green{
    background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I am expecting to have 1/8 of the buttons to be yellow. That being the clicked button.

Comment: Your code appears to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/4ez70dyt/ Is something else on the page breaking it perhaps?

Comment: @Gavin, did you add the first line `let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');` to get it working? That is what is needed.

Comment: I did yes. Sorry I thought you'd omitted it intentionally!

Comment: i tried this exactly and still not having the expected result. I am using express, nodemon, nodeJS and path in the project. I can link github link if helpful

Comment: @Gavin, i have used the code straight from fiddle and it still doesnt work in the server. Do i have to reload and reserve after the function executes if I am serving up with express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than toggling the yellow and green classes - you can simply add a  'highlight' class on click and remove it from the previously clicked button.

This highlight class has the yellow background styling, so that when you click a button it adds the highlight class and yellow background. Then clicking another button removes the highlight class from the first button and applies it to the clicked one.

```js
 var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
 
 for (button in buttons) {
    buttons[button].onclick = function() {
        console.log('test')
        buttons.forEach(function(btn){
          btn.classList.remove('highlight');
        })
        this.classList.add('highlight');
    }
}
```

```css
button{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.green{
    background-color: green;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="green">UPKEEP</button>
<button class="green">DRAW</button>
<button class="green">MAIN</button>
<button class="green">COMBAT</button>
<button class="green">MAIN</button>
<button class="green">END TURN</button>
<button class="green">CLEANUP</button>
```

Comment: i tried this exactly and still not having the expected result. I am using express, nodemon, nodeJS and path in the project. I can link github link if helpful

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get your code to work. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkzusmj4/)

Make sure you define `buttons` correctly:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".green");
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in my html, i had to move the script tag to the end of the body to allow loop to occur. Thanks for the help folks!